# UIImageView skewed image

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView`. When it displays its first image in landscape mode, the image appears skewed towards the top, like a 3D view (or perspective skewing). In other words, the it list the top left and right corners of the image are pushed in towards the center.

When the second image loads, it goes back to normal.

It does not appear to occur in Portrait mode.

How can I get rid of that behavior?

As requested:

```
UIImageView *chartView ;
chartView.image = image ;
```

The first time in landscape, skewed. All subsequent times normal.

Comment: Share some code where you displaying image. Otherwise it hard to help.. :)

Comment: some more code? where do you laythem out ? how do handle it ?

Comment: The layout code is quite extensive and complicated. Each image is a segment in a chart using a Lambert conical projection. The images have to be transformed to fit the current view point. Oddly, this only occurs the first time loaded.

Comment: What contentmode are you using?

Comment: UIViewContentModeScaleToFill [Unchanged]